# Finding end tags with Python ElementTree XML API

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

While parsing some XML I want to determine if I have encountered an end tag of a particular element. Is this possible via the ElementTree XML API?

Sample XML:

```
<data>
  <folder name="a">
  <folder name="b">
    <file name="a1">
    </file>
  </folder>
  <file name="b2">
  </file>
  </folder>
</data>
```

For example: before accessing `<file name="b2">` in the XML above, I want to be able to know that a `</folder>` has already been encountered.

Comment: You mean you want to know when you encounter the '</folder>' for <folder name="a"> ?

Comment: Not specific to <folder name="a">. But just </folder>.
For eg: in VC++ we have node type as "End Node" to determine whether its a closing tag or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ElementTree.fromstring()

Assume that your xml file like this:

xml1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <data>
      <folder name="a">
          <folder name="b">
            <file name="a1">
            </file>
          </folder>
      <file name="b2">
      </file>
      </folder>
    </data>
```

xml2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <data>
      <folder name="a">
          <folder name="b">
            <file name="a1">
            </file>
          </folder>
      <file name="b2">
      </file>

    </data>
```

When you call  `ElementTree.fromstring(open('xml1.xml').read())`, it will finish correctly.
When you call  `ElementTree.fromstring(open('xml2.xml').read())`, it will raise an error, called `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag`, which means your folder tag isn't complete.

If this answers your question, please confirm it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for providing the solution but the problem that I am facing is somewhat diff. The XML that i get is completely correct, I want to know the ending tag so as to take certain decisions for the next file tag.
I have anyways used recursion to solve the problem, but still wanted to know if it is possible to determine that the tag is a closing or not ?